# Theoretiaclly: How to extend core functionality with an extension. oop php

Tags: php, oop

I have question that is theoretically about OOP and PHP. With a CMS system that is extensible, it must be possible to overwrite core code with the extension code.

But with the keyword extends in the definition of the subclass we can not change the core-functionality but only clone it as subclass and then change the functionality. It only works if we instantiate the code with the name of the new subclass... Is it not possible to change core-code that is instantiated with the baseclass name?

It should return ret - funtionalitätret - funtionalität
But return core - funtionalitätret - funtionalität

```
    class core_example {
        function __construct() {

        }
        function ret() {
            echo "core - funktionalität";
        }
    }
    class extension extends core_example{
        function ret() {
            echo "ret - funtionalität";
        }
    }

$core = new core_example();
$extension = new extension();
$core->ret();
$extension->ret();
```

Comment: Have a look at dependency injection and overriden services, that might help

Comment: But when extending a CMS fe WP with extensions. In the plugins folder are several plugins. When the core class is instantiated for the CMS generation isnt there an modification of its functionality taking place according to the plugins in the folder?

Comment: I don't get that - what is "a CMS fe WP"? After all, it obviously depends on the way the plugins are loaded, so if you already have a structure in mind, you should share it. Through a DI container, you can easily swap out such plugins or extend them

Comment: If you have a CMS like Wordpress... are the plugins there not able to override core code in a way that the core functionality globally changes? So when the wp core class is instantiated it contains already the modification through the plugin? Or can we only work with our subclass instances to access modified core-functionality?

Comment: Are you asking for core principles of OOP? If you extend a class and override a method, then a call using the extended class to the given method calls the overriden method. The missing piece might be that WP (or any other CMS) won't pick up the overriden class if it would not use a real DI container. But then it's not a theoretical question anymore, as it depends very hardly on the used CMS